# Fixing Ubuntu Installation after aborted Installation attempt

Tags: boot, mount, 16.04, initramfs

My Ubuntu Desktop was restarted because of some reason while upgrading to 16.04 from 14.04. Now, when I restart, the Ubuntu starts, but drops to initramfs shell, and says "Mounting /dev on /root/dev failed no such file or directory".

I booted with Ubuntu Live CD mounted /dev/sda6 which previously had my Ubuntu installation, and did chroot.

ls shows no etc directory (there is no /mnt/etc). Following is the output of ls /mnt

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt$ ls /mnt/
boot  BootInfo  boot-sav  cdrom  home  include  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  root  run  snap  srv  tmp  ubiquity-apt-clone  usr  var
```

Is it possible to salvage this distribution?

As a follow up question, is it possible to install Ubuntu to /dev/sda6 without erasing existing data? The only options I see in Install RELEASE of Live USB are

1. Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu
2. Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation For Security
3. Use LVM with new Ubuntu Installation
4. Something else

Comment: Partial installations can have all sorts of problems which is why you should always backup before upgrades. If you backed up, restore your backup and try again. Otherwise you should boot an ISO disk/usb and reinstall without formatting.

Comment: Hi Dorian, thanks for replying. Would it be possible to install Ubuntu to /dev/sda6 without losing the existing data (Its ok for me to lose any and all OS files, I just don't want to have to rebuild the Dev environment I've set up, like JVM, databases, etc. and not have to move data files)?

Comment: If you reinstall, when it comes to partitioning, choose "Something Else" and just choose to install root(/) on /dev/sda6 and make sure the format checkbox is NOT checked.  It will install the OS overtop of everything, but won't delete things.  Packages and programs might need to be reinstalled but your files will still be there.  Just make sure to choose the same username and password as before.

Answer (score 2):

As per our conversation, reinstall Ubuntu using a boot CD or USB.

When partitioning, choose "Something else".

Choose to install root (/) on the same partition you had before.  If you had any other folders such as /home on other partitions, make sure you select those as well.  Ensure that the format checkbox is UNCHECKED.

Ensure you create your user with the same name and password as before.

This will install Ubuntu in the same places as before, overwriting anything that was there before, but it will not delete any files.

You may have to reinstall some packages for them to work correctly, but any data/files you had before will still be there.  You may have to change any preference settings back to what you had before, such as backgrounds, color themes, font sizes etc.